# Is it possible to select one column in Symfony using form builder queries

Tags: php, sql, forms, symfony

I've got a simple issue when trying to populate a select box when the form builder tries to populate the select statement as it outputs an array instead of a single string. I believe I may be doing this incorrectly however I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution to the proplem.

Form builder class:

```
<?php

namespace Test\TesterBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Test\TesterBundle\Model\CategoryQuery;
use Test\TesterBundle\Model\CategoryPeer;

class ProductsType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('ProductName')
                ->add('ProductDescription', 'textarea', array("required"=> false))
                ->add('ShortDescription', null)
                ->add('SKU', null)
                ->add('UnitWeight', null)
                ->add('UnitPrice', null)
                ->add('UnitLength', null)
                ->add('UnitHeight', null)
                ->add('UnitDepth', null)
                ->add('URL', null)
                ->add('MetaTitle', null)
                ->add('MetaDescription', null)
                ->add('MetaKeywords', null)
                ->add('ProductID', 'model', array(
                        'class' => 'Test\TesterBundle\Model\Productcategory',
                        'required' => false,
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'expanded' => false,
                        'label'    => "Select form the below",
                        'query'    => CategoryQuery::create()->select(array("CategoryName"))->orderByCategoryName(),
                    ))
                ->add('save', 'submit')
                ->getForm();
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('newProducts'),
            'data_class' => 'Test\TesterBundle\Model\Products'
        ));
    }

    public function getName(){
        return "Products";
    }


}
```

When it trys to populate the select area it shows the following error:

> Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in
>   /var/www/Test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ObjectChoiceList.php
>   line 256

And this is the part of the stacktrace it is showing:

```
        } elseif (method_exists($choice, '__toString')) {
            $labels[$i] = (string) $choice;
        } else {
            throw new StringCastException(sprintf('A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type "%s" passed to the choice field. To read a custom getter instead, set the argument $labelPath to the desired property path.', get_class($choice)));
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone Know where I am going wrong? I want to select one column and populate the selects with the results of the column name. If I change the query to:

```
'query'    => CategoryQuery::create()->orderByCategoryName(),
```

It populates one of the fields with all columns of the last record. Can anyone advise or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does the entity have a `__toString()` function?

Comment: @sjagr I'm fairly new to the formbuilding process so I haven't got an entity as I didn't beleive I needed one. I'm using propel so it is using the model. Do I need to create a __toString() function in there?

Comment: Correct, if you're not using a `property` field in the builder you need to define a `__toString()` in the Entity/Model so the builder knows what value to pull from when displaying the drop-down list.

Comment: @sjagr Thank you I shall give that a try when I get in front of the code. To be honest I wasn't even aware of the properties field. Upon further reading it seems like that will be the issue. If you want to post it as the answer I shall mark it as correct once I have tested it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `property` attribute when you were building the form. Without that, the builder will try to find a `__toString()` function to be able to properly abstract a collection of models (normally entities) as a list. Something like:

```
function __toString() {
    return $this->getName(); // Assuming $this->getName() exists
}
```

should suffice. Best of luck!